# PHP Загрузка файлов на сервер (Права доступа)

Tags: php

Написал скрипт для загрузки, и дальнейшего отображения изображения на странице.
Собственно вот сам сценарий, вместе с разметкой. 
Проблема заключается в том, что изображение загружается на сервер, но не отображается на странице. Сервер возвращает 404 ошибку. Папку uploads я предварительно создал на сервере, изображения туда попадают, но когда пытаюсь открыть их из этой папки, пишет - "Похоже у вас нет разрешения для просмотра этого файла. Проверьте свои разрешения и повторите попытку".
Я так и подразумевал что проблема с правами доступа, подскажите как их установить, как это делается в настоящих проектах на сайтах? Спасибо!

```html
<?php
 $uploaded = null;

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if (isset($_FILES['avatar'])) {
   $uploaded = true;

   $file_name = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
   $file_path = __DIR__ . '/uploads/';
   $file_url = '/uploads/' . $file_name;

   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['avatar']['tmp_name'], $file_path . $file_name);
  }
 }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Upload files in php</title>
 <style>
  img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
  }

  .container {
   width: 900px;
   padding: 0 10px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   border-left: 1px solid #000;
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
  }

  .avatar {
   background-color: #eee;
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <form method="post" action="files.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="avatar">
   <button type="submit">Upload image</button>
  </form>
  <div class="avatar">
   <?php if ($uploaded): ?>
    <img src="<?= $file_url; ?>" alt="<?= $file_name; ?>">
   <?php endif ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Comment: @RomanAndreev , А как его правильно интегрировать в мой сценарий? Есть какие-то примеры?

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев, выполнить в консоли вашей *nix системы.

Comment: @ЭлчинХасиев можете скинуть полный URL изображения. при 404 ошибке

Comment: Вам просто нужно на папку upload права нужные поставит через ftp и всё.

Comment: Ну да, путь неверный показывает ..  http://localhost/uploads/имя_файла.расширение .. Не рабочий мой скрипт, буду думать дальше.

Comment: "@ЭлчинХасиев `$file_path` напишите, что хранится в данной переменной(значение)

Comment: @ЕвгенийНиколаев, C:\Server\data\htdocs\site/uploads/ . Спасибо! Теперь я так понимаю ошибка в слешах? Не знаете что с этим сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел причину. В моем случае

```html
$file_url = '/uploads/' . $file_name;
```

Перед uploads ненужен слеш. Ниже исправленный вариант.

```html
$file_url = 'uploads/' . $file_name;
```